# Functional Components to Class Components

Tags: reactjs

So I realized that now when we create a react app, it is by default in functional. So I was wondering if there was any way to change that into classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can chang your existing functional component to class based component like this

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>;
  }
}
```

I would suggest you to go through react documentation which has everything explained very well with working excercises.

Check it -
[React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Answer (score 1):

if your `App.js` code looks like this:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>REACT APP</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can turn it into a class based component by importing `Component` and a bit of refactor like below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>REACT APP</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

1. The `class` App will extend `Componment`
2. Your JSX will be returned in the `render()` function of your class